# Loopback: escape default include

Tags: loopbackjs

I have a hasMany relation between two models, say user and team. Now if I query a user I also want to get his/her team, so I put this in the user.json file

```
"scope" : {"include":["team"]}
```

Also, if I query for a team i want to get all the users of that team, so in the team.json file I put

```
"scope" : {"include":["users"]}
```

Now, (as expected) this does not work. A query hangs because a user includes his team which inculdes its users, each ow these users include the team again , and so on. The query is never resolved.

I tried to solve the problem by putting this in the user.json file (replacing what I showed earlier)

```
"scope" : {"include":[{"team":[]}]}
```

Unfortunately this does not work.

How to solve this problem? Is there a way to tell loopback to include a related model but none of it's relations?